# How will you resolve this network of resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Just found this in a test and was thinking how would you resolve this network of resistance.
**P.S: only focus on the triangular part**

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Y-$\Delta$" transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) sequentially to untangle the network.